# Django Form Upload Files no data in request.FILES

Tags: python, django, file-upload, httprequest

I am trying to store files that are uploaded from a django form. I upload the files in a report form and I would like to store the files on my server so I can access them later.

My Model:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    content = models.TextField()
    security = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My Form:

```
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=128)
    content = forms.TextInput()
    security = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False, label="Private")
    files = forms.FileField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ('description','content','security','files',)
```

My View:

```
def index(request):
    report_list=Report.objects.all()
    report_form=ReportForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if report_form.is_valid():
        report = report_form.save()
        report.author = request.user
        report.save()
        for count, x in enumerate(request.FILES.getlist("files")):
            with open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'wb+') as destination:
                for chunk in x.chunks():
                    destination.write(chunk)
    context_dict = {'Reports' : report_list, 'Report_Form' : report_form}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context_dict)
```

My HTML:

```
<form id="report_form", method="post",action="/myapplication/",enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h3>New Report:</h3>
        {% csrf_token %}

        <label for="id_description">Description:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="id_description" maxlength="128" name="description" type="text"/>
        <label for="id_content">Content:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="id_content" maxlength="2000" name="content" type="text"/>
        <label for="id_files">Files:</label>
        <input type="file" name="files" multiple>
        <label for="id_security">Security:</label>
        Public <input type="radio" id="id_security" name="security" value="False" checked>
        Private <input type="radio" id="id_security" name="security" value="True">
        <br>
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
```

Why can't I find the uploaded files in request.FILES?

Comment: Your HTML is broken - commas in the `<form>` tag are invalid and breaking the attributes. Remove them and it should work.

Comment: bonehead mistake... Thanks so much, I've got it working now